# Creating table entry with params hash and associated model(s) params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

i want to do something like this:

```
user.items << Item.new(params[:item] , :computer => Computer.new(params[:computer] , :laptop => Laptop.new(params[:laptop])))
```

But this generates an error "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is actually interpreted as

```
Item.new(params[:item] , {
  :computer => Computer.new(params[:computer], { 
    :laptop => Laptop.new(params[:laptop])
  })
})
```

`#new` expects a hash attribute, and you're giving it two hashes. One solution would be to merge the hashes using `Hash#merge`.

Comment: Thanks, 'merge' works perfectly... `item = Item.new(params[:item].merge({:computer => Computer.new(params[:computer].merge({:laptop => Laptop.new(params[:laptop])}))}))`